# Send a mail from the free server 260mb

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail, cpanel, phpmailer

I'm trying to send mails from my CodeIgniter webpage with PHPMailer. In fact, my code worked perfectly in localhost but when I uploaded it to the server (whose name's 260mb), I got this error message:

SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.

These are the most important lines of my code (I don't write the other because they work well on localhost):

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password_of_myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->From = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'John';
$mail->AddAddress('otheremail@gmail.com');
```

After this, I tried to create two email accounts on my server, one of them for sending the message and the other to receive it. The changes I made on my code are these:

```
$mail->Host = 'localhost'; //Because both email accounts are on the server;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = 'phpmailerfrom@mydomain.260mb.net';
$mail->Password = 'password_of_phpmailerfrom@mydomain.260mb.net';
$mail->From = 'phpmailerfrom@mydomain.260mb.net';
$mail->FromName = 'John';
$mail->AddAddress('phpmailerto@mydomain.260mb.net');
```

But in this case the errors are:

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 
The following From address failed: phpmailerfrom@mydomain.260mb.net

I would appreciate a lot any help, especially if you could solve the first situation. I looked for a lot of information and may be the problem is the free server, in that case, how can I authorize mails in 260mb cPanel??

Thank you.

Comment: Your webhost is 260mb as well as being your mail host? You're throwing around a lot of server/hoster names, but not explaining exactly how they relate to your problem

Comment: My guess is that they (smtp.gmail.com) block connections from servers to make it harder for bots to send mail.

Comment: From localhost you use gmail, and from your hosted site you use their mail server?  Who's your actual mail host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help, but actually I could find the answer for my first question (not the second one):

I had to click here:

[Unlock Google mail account](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

And type the Google email which I was using to send mails in my code, and its password.

Now, the first code I wrote in my question works.